# How to display SVG Sprite Icons in HTML file while working locally?

Tags: html, css, svg, icons, svg-sprite

I am using SVG icons (from IcoMoon), the problem is I can't see the icons while working locally, but when I upload the page online it works fine.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SVG Icons</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <svg class="ico ico-menu"><use xlink:href="icons/symbol-defs.svg#ico-menu"></use></svg></td>
    <script defer src="icons/svgxuse.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not using any local server. It is a plain HTML file. I wonder how can I fix this issue?

Thank You

Comment: Use a local server.

Comment: @RobertLongson, even for one static HTML page?

Comment: @RobertLongson, using a local server solved the issue. Thanks a lot :-)